# How does applicative sequencing over a list of functions work?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell with the [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) guide, and I'm stuck on an example of applicative sequencing over a list of functions. [Chapter 11: Functors, Applicative Functors and Monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) defines sequenceA to be:

```
sequenceA :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA [] = pure []
sequenceA (x:xs) = (:) <$> x <*> sequenceA xs
```

I'm a bit confounded by this example usage of sequenceA:

```
> sequenceA [(+3),(+2),(+1)] 3
[6,5,4]
```

I've expanded the application manually as far as I could to what I believe is correct:

```
(:) <$> (+3) <*> sequenceA [(+2), (+1)]
(:) <$> (+3) <*> (:) <$> (+2) <*> (:) <$> (+1) <*> sequenceA []
(:) <$> (+3) <*> (:) <$> (+2) <*> (:) <$> (+1) <*> pure []
(:) <$> (+3) <*> (:) <$> (+2) <*> (:) <$> (+1) <*> const []
```

What I don't see though, is how the second argument to the original application of sequenceA, `3` gets applied to each of the partially applied functions given in the list. I would appreciate some assistance in trying to wrap my head around what goes on in the evaluation of this statement.

Comment: Hint: The Applicative instance is `(->) a`. Work out the `fmap`/`<*>` application!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever you're dealing with generic types you need to first determine what the concrete type is. In this case, we have

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
```

applied to

```
[(+3),(+2),(+1)] :: Num a => [a -> a]
```

In other words, though it's a bit bizarre to see at first, `f` becomes `a ->` (properly written `(->) a`) and so the type of `sequenceA`, specialized, is

```
sequenceA :: Num a => [a -> a] -> a -> [a]
```

Which should already explain where that extra argument came from.

---

So how does `sequenceA` work? To understand, we need to understand the `Applicative` instance for `(->) a`. In particular

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
  fmap f g = f . g

instance Applicative ((->) a) where
  pure a'   = \a -> a'
  ff <*> fx = \a -> (ff a) (fx a)
```

where we see that `(<*>)` takes two functions and produces a third. The argument from this third function is applied to each of the input functions (here, `ff` and `fx`) and then their results are applied to one another.

So application in the `(->) a` monad means that the ultimate argument `a` to the result is distributed to all of the compositional functions.

And this is what we see with `sequenceA`

```
sequenceA [(+3),(+2),(+1)]
==
\a -> [(a + 3), (a + 2), (a + 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful explanation, J! :) I believe I have something after playing around with ghci for a while:

`> ((:) . (+3) $ 3) (((:) . (+2) $ 3) (((:) . (+1) $ 3) (const [] 3)))`
`[6,5,4]`

Although I must admit, I still don't fully understand how the 3 gets distributed. I see the infix fmap operator makes a function to take the 3, but it's hard for me to imagine it does indeed get sent to all functions. Maybe there's a better way to explain it, or if not, hopefully its understanding that comes with more practice.

Comment: Perhaps further study of `sequenceA` would be useful then. Try taking a look at it in other applicatives or monads (`Reader` will be important!). In plain terms, `sequenceA` takes several effectful computations and "shares" their effects in sequence. Thus the name. For function application sequence doesn't matter, but sharing does.

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

we can derive:

```
      (:) <$> (+3) <*> (      (:) <$> (+2) <*> (     (:) <$> (+1) <*> const [] ))
 pure (:) <*> (+3) <*> ( pure (:) <*> (+2) <*> ( pure (:) <*> (+1) <*> const [] ))
const (:) <*> (+3) <*> (const (:) <*> (+2) <*> (const (:) <*> (+1) <*> const [] ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+2)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+1)) <*> const [] ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+2)) <*> ((\x -> (const (:)) x (x+1)) <*> const [] ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+2)) <*> ((\x -> (:) (x+1)) <*> const [] ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+2)) <*> (\y -> (\x -> (:) (x+1)) y (const [] y) ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+2)) <*> (\y -> (\x -> (:) (x+1)) y [] ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+2)) <*> (\y -> ((y+1):) [] ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> ((const (:) <*> (+2)) <*> (\y -> [y+1] ))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> (((\x -> (const (:)) x (x+2)) <*> (\y -> [y+1] ))

(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> (\z -> ((\x -> (const (:)) x (x+2)) z ((\y -> [y+1] )z))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> (\z -> (((const (:)) z (z+2))  ([z+1]))
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> (\z -> ((z+2):)  [z+1])
(const (:) <*> (+3)) <*> (\z -> [z+2,z+1])
(\x -> (const (:)) x (x+3)) <*> (\z -> [z+2,z+1])
(\x -> const (:) (x+3)) <*> (\z -> [z+2,z+1])
(\x -> ((x+3):)) <*> (\z -> [z+2,z+1])
\w -> (\x -> ((x+3):)) w ((\z -> [z+2,z+1]) w)
\w -> ((w+3):) [w+2,w+1]
\w -> [w+3,w+2,w+1]
```

I bet I messed up some parentheses